# Unable to activate windows store app the app didn't start

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, windows-8.1

First of all I would like to say that I already tried all the solutions I could find on the internet, including [Unable to Activate Windows Store App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13404315/unable-to-activate-windows-store-app)

I recently upgraded my Windows 7 machine to Windows 8.1 to be capable of developing Windows Store apps using Visual Studio 2013. When I open a blank project (Windows Store -> Blank App) and run it I get this error:

> Unable to activate Windows Store app 'Package Name'. The App1.exe
> process started, but the activation request failed with error 'The app
> didn't start'.
>
> See help for advice on troubleshooting the issue.

I already tried:

- Reinstalling Windows (Clean install)
- Reinstalling Visual Studio 2013
- Installing Visual Studio 2012 (same error)
- Deleting "bin" and "obj" folder
- Cleaning the solution
- Uninstalling the app from start menu
- Creating a new project
- Acquiring the license multiple times (the license is valid)
- Making sure that app.config doesn't exist
- Investigating the Windows Event Log which says

> Activation of the app 'Package Name' for the Windows.Launch contract failed with error: The app didn't start..

but found nothing useful

- Adding a new Windows user
- Run everything as administrator
- and at last, changing the desktop background

None of this did bring a solution. Does anyone have an idea what else could be the reason for this error?

Comment: I'm having the same problem with both VS2012 and 2013, yet I've already tried everything on this page and still no resolution... any ideas?

Comment: [This solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36149356/1277458) is solving the similar issue. The problem was related with User Account Control (UAC) settings.
Those error messages are absolutely unuseful. Thanks to this guy I've solved mine.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found a solution. The problem was that the drive I was working on was encrypted (TrueCrypt). Moving the output folder to an unencrypted drive solved the problem.

Comment: The same. What on earth it that? Why TrueCrypt influences in such way?

Comment: TrueCrypt was the source of the problem that I was experiencing as well.

Comment: How do I know if my drive is encrypted?

Answer (score 10):

If switching from x86 to x64, make sure your Project Properties Platform Target and Configuration Platform are BOTH set to X64.Hint you need to change to x64 debugging in the Build menu/Configuration Manager dialog to get the Configuration Platform in Project Properties to update.

This caused the activation error problem to be resolved for me.

Comment: This is what eventually worked for me too. It's so infuriating.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same Error and tried after loading the SQLite Package for WP 8.1 some things above:

not working:

- Clean and Rebuild
- Restart Computer/Phone

what did the deal (for me)

- I put `Platform Target` under `Properties` -> `Build` to **ARM** instead of **x86**

Hopefully this might help somebody else facing this ridiculously informative Errormessage.

Comment: This was my issue as well.

Comment: I found just changing the build type to another value resolved it for me (in my case x64)  Thank you though!

Comment: This appears to do something indeed. Changing to Debug x64 will work. Changing to Release x86 will work. Changing back to the default Debug x86 the problem remains, however.

Comment: @Eric do you maybe use third party binaries (plugins, ...) that are only provided as release?

Comment: I don't think so. I'm using some packages (UWP Community Toolkit, Newtonsoft.Json), project references (Universal Windows and .NET Standard 1.4) and the default references+extensions from Add Reference. I should say this problem is new. The same solution didn't have this before.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem with Visual Studio Community 2015 while trying to debug an Blank App (Universal Windows) using Visual C#.

Visual Studio was installed on Disk C:(SSD), and Project files were placed on D:(HDD). I´ve created a Folder on C: Drive and placed my test project there.
After that Error messages gone.

Comment: I had the same problem. Even though I don't have different physical disks, copying my project from D to C solved the problem.

Comment: So, I finally found something for this on MSDN: [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f34da155-a4ad-4933-ba82-071de9c7c0b3/uwp-apps-fail-to-launch-and-xaml-designer-crashes-if-visual-studio-and-windows-store-apps-are-both?forum=Win10SDKToolsIssues)

Answer (score 3):

If you are receiving this error and are developing for **Microsoft Hololens:**

You are trying to build to a device that is asleep. To wake your device, tap on the button on the back (on/off button).

Answer (score 2):

I've tried all the solutions found on the net and none applied to my case, not even this one.

The only way I could make it work was changing the Package Name in the appxmanifest.
This made me think there must be some leftovers somewhere around with the old package name, that are either corrupted or inaccessible because of some permissions issues.

It might be just a coincidence but the problem appeared twice after I tried using the app verifier (appverif.exe)

Now I reassociated my app to a store app package and things seem to continue working...

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: It provides another way to solve the "unable to activate the app" by changing the Package Name in the appxmanifest.

Comment: No matter what the package name becomes it keeps giving the error

Answer (score 2):

In my solution, I have a non-UWP project (Multiplatform development) that builds with a different Solution Platform.

I was attempting to run the UWP project in Debug, but as the wrong Solution Platform.

**Edit:**
I also get this when I build my project for Any-CPU, instead of x64.

Comment: I also had this issue and this was the fix!

I had been trying for ages, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that `ALL APPLICATION PACKAGES` has "read" permissions on `C:\Windows`.

My organization's group policy likes to strip all permissions from `C:\Windows`, including the `ALL APPLICATION PACKAGES` group . By adding it back in and setting `Read & execute`, `List folder contents`, and `Read`, I'm able to run the app from Visual Studio without any problems.

See [What to do if your Windows 8 Modern App fails to start](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2013/10/11/what-to-do-if-your-windows-8-modern-app-fails-to-start.aspx) for more tips, including this one.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem in Visual Studio 2015 Update 3, Windows 10 Build 10586.494.

The error came up when trying to start *any* UWP app that I compiled *without* .NET Native Toolchain. With Native Toolchain enabled, the apps would start.

Installing a new (blank) app manually fixed the error for me:

- Start VS 2015
- File > New > Project.
- Blank App (Universal Windows) Visual C#. OK.
- Make sure to be in Debug config
- Right click on Project > Store > Create App Packages
- No. Next.
- Select Debug for all architectures.
- Create
- When packaging is finished, open Explorer to the project path / AppPackages / [...]_Debug_Test
- Right-click on Add-AppDevPackage.ps1 > Run with PowerShell
- Follow the instructions
- Start the installed app from Start Menu

Answer (score 0):

A simple restart helped me out.

Also tried this one?: http://irisclasson.com/2012/11/04/problem-unable-to-activate-windows-store-app-the-app1-exe-process-started-but-the-activation-request-failed-with-error-the-app-didnt-start/

Comment: I have already tried that (even a fresh install), but it didn't help. I also knew about the app.config, but there is no app.confing in my project or folder on disk.

Comment: What version of Visual Studio do you use, and is your developer license connected to your Microsoft account?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix the same problem by rebuilding the solution. (In Vis Studio 2012)

Answer (score 0):

I have tried many solutions and nothing worked.  At the end what worked for me was to change the startup project to windows phone 8.1 and after it runs OK I changed it back to windows 8.1 and it runs OK.  It works for me as I am making a universal app. Hope it helps anyone else.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with a Windows Store App after moving some files around.  I ended up opening an older file (as Admin) to see if it would run and found that it did.  I then returned to the file that would not and it ran also.  I believe opening the older file (as Admin) reset the paths for development and the permissions.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, solved by choosing a new publisher certificate. And of course restarting Windows

Answer (score 0):

Moved my project from the TrueCrypt Partition and all was fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue. Selecting proper Platform solved my problem. i.e. My application was selected to run under x86 platform, while my OS & SDK supports x64. Selecting x64 solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on a UWP app when creating a package for Testing, but not when runing directly from Visual Studio 2017.

[image]

The solution was to select only the architecture that I am using to Debug the App, Instead of all options (x86, x64, ARM).

[image]

Here is the option choosed on Visual Studio
[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are can be a couple of things that might be causing this problem.
Here are the trouble shooting steps that helped me out:

**Step 1 :** Check to see if running visual studio in the elevated mode (**Run as an Administrator**) helped solve the problem. (Sometimes, your folder permissions might get mangled due to various softwares that you might have install)

**Step 2 :** Delete all the **bin** and **obj** folders in your project and rebuild the projects in your solution manually.

**Step 3 :** Do a quick check of your **System Type** **(x64 or x86 etc)** and see if your project is targeted for the same.

Here is how to do know your system type:  `Win + R > cmd > systeminfo`

If it says x64, then make sure to select the **Solution Platforms** (In visual studios top action bar)  as x64 or so forth depending on your architecture.

That's all I did to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had unticked an option while trying to get debugging working prior to this error, the fix for me was to re-check the "Compile with .NET Native tool chain"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A rather niche situation and solution...

I was remote debugging a UWP app for a while successfully. After some reworking, I ran into this issue. In the main app project I had set the windows version compatibility accordingly (I am running the app on a Windows 10 IoT Enterprise 2019 device) but had forgotten to match those windows target and minimum versions for the Library Project that was in my solution.

After cleaning and re-deploying the solution (first uninstalling the app from the remote device), the problem went away.