# Universal App Deploy error code: 2147942411

Tags: visual-studio-2013, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

After porting a Windows Phone 8.0 app into a Universal Windows App I get the compile error

> DEP6810 : MdilXapCompile.exe failed with error code 2001.

When building for `Release`, building for `Debug` on an emulator works fine.

In the log file I get the message

> CrossGen failed
>
> Raw error code: 2147942411

I found that this was [asked on msdn](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7b96740f-2b4e-463d-9ed4-bbd5ae96e1fa/wp81-universal-app-deploy-error-code-2147942411?forum=wpdevelop), but the answer is not very helpful. They say it's a `ERROR_BAD_FORMAT`.

Has anyone ran into this issue and found a solution?

---

Since msdn question asked, I am using Visual Studio 2013 with update 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was the `platform target`

When you build for Windows Phone use `platform target`

> Device : **ARM**
>
> Emulator: **x86** or **x64**

After this issue, I got [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19847563/unable-to-activate-windows-store-app-the-app-didnt-start) which I recommend you check out (I don't know if they are linked in some way)

---

So I ran into this issue again

#### Working Configuration

I had this settings configuration:

- Platform: Active(Any CPU)
- Platform target: ARM

[image]

#### Breaking the configuration

To enable the error message

> DEP6810 : MdilXapCompile.exe failed with error code 2001.

just simply change the `Platform` from `Active(Any CPU)` to `ARM` (I expect anything will do)

Now, even if you change the `Platform` back from `ARM` to `Active(Any CPU)` it still gives the error.

#### Solution

1. Uninstall the app from the device
2. Restart the device (and your computer if you feel like it)
3. Deploy the build again

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue:

```
Error 1 Error : DEP6810 : MdilXapCompile.exe failed with error code 2001.
```

changing from `release` to `debug` resolved the error. [This](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/d0b940d2-1c4e-4f28-9130-b45067088aa1/vs2013-update-2-wp-81-arm-deploying-to-device-problem-dep6810-in-release-mode?forum=wpdevelop&prof=required) MSDN post helped me solve it.

Comment: how is this a resolution since we usually need to publish in release

Answer (score 0):

I was having similar issues (same error). What solved it for me was moving my solution mapping from my local c: drive to my user folder. I'm thinking it was some sort of permissions issue that was being masked by this error.