# Building WP app to phone App didn't start error

Tags: windows, debugging, windows-phone-8, build, universal

We are having an issue building my app in Debug mode to my physical devices, the error is posted below.

The device is dev unlocked and was working, but stopped with no warning. We can still work on the emulator and build in release mode to the device.

We have tried:
•Reassociating it with the Windows Phone store.
•Cleaning the solution.
•Deleting obj and bin folders.
•Rebuilding solutions
•Running VS in admin mode.
•Restarting the system.

Does anyone please have advice on how to resolve this issue as it is hurting our beta testing.

Error:

"Unable to activate Windows Store app 'App Name'. The Process started, but the activation request failed with error 'The app didn't start'"

Comment: I'm seeing multiple solutions when i google it, it can be different things. What options didn't work for you so far?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to activate windows store app the app didn't start](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19847563/unable-to-activate-windows-store-app-the-app-didnt-start)

Answer (score 0):

try to remove the App.config file

Comment: I have, with no luck :( Not sure why this issue is occurring.

Comment: It's strange. See :https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/fd4163fe-41c1-4c23-bc8d-be20cc5a70c3/error-code-the-app-didnt-start?forum=winappswithcsharp

Comment: or http://irisclasson.com/2012/11/04/problem-unable-to-activate-windows-store-app-the-app1-exe-process-started-but-the-activation-request-failed-with-error-the-app-didnt-start/

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the app installed on device, it will fail when you try to deploy using Visual studio. Is this a Windows Phone 8.1 app or 7.x app?