# Data area passed to a system is too small error in UWP app

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp, visual-studio-debugging

My UWP app is building,rebuilding and deploying fine but it is not running.
Although, it works fine in other system.

I am using Visual Studio professional 2015 since 5 month to build this project and all of a sudden it has started showing this.[image: Data area is too small]
When i try to uninstall the app it doesn't give any option to uninstall also.[image: No Uninstall Option]

I have tried restarting the system and cleaning,rebuilding the project file but nothing seems to work.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the directory or the folder were corrupted so that is why every time when i was running the application it was installing in a non packaged version therefore i was not getting the option to uninstall it properly.

I tried by deleting the whole folder which created in AppData folder of the Users but it didn't work.

So finally i created a new folder and moved my solution over there.And everything is working pretty much fine now.I thought we could solve this problem by repairing Visual Studio but since this issue is not related with Visual Studio and moreover it takes half of your day to repair Visual Studio so only moving the project to a newly created folder would be a good idea in this case.

Comment: Glad to know that you have resolved this issue, you could mark it as the answer:)

Answer (score 0):

**Causes:**

It is a known issue in Visual Studio 2015.

For more info: [unable to activate Windows Store app](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/07816379-eee7-4834-ba64-4d5ef2f1e68c/application-is-not-executing-when-the-file-is-in-d-drive-but-it-is-executing-when-the-same-file-is?forum=vsdebug)

**Solution:**

Update to Visual Studio 2017

For other solutions:
[Unable to activate windows store app the app didn't start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19847563/unable-to-activate-windows-store-app-the-app-didnt-start)
[Unable to activate Windows Store app: The App1.exe process started, but the activation request failed with error ‘The app didn’t start’](http://irisclasson.com/2012/11/04/problem-unable-to-activate-windows-store-app-the-app1-exe-process-started-but-the-activation-request-failed-with-error-the-app-didnt-start/)

Comment: Thanks Vijay. I guess when the folder gets corrupted or visual studio does not respond well in that case we get this type of error(Ex: 'the app didn't start' or 'the data area passed to system is too small'.). I copied the solution in a newly created folder and everything started working or this problem could be solved by repairing the visual studio.

Comment: @tushargoyal1309, I just got this issue before which was related to the project's directory. Anyway, since it works well now, you could post your solution as an answer and them mark it later:)