# Activation of the Windows Store app ... failed with error 'The app didn't start'

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-10, windows-10-universal, windows-10-desktop

**ISSUE**

Unable to start any UWP app (blank app, UWP samples) in Release/x86.

However, Debug/x86, Debug/x64, Release/x64 are OK.

**RELATED**

1. Build -> Configuration Manager
2. New...
3. Copy Settings from Debug
4. Same error

**ERROR**

Visual Studio Output

```
Symbols for ntdll.dll could not be downloaded from the Microsoft Symbol Servers. Exception settings and call stacks may not work correctly.  Make sure you have a network connection and try again.'App1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

The thread 0x2e74 has exited with code -1073741792 (0xc0000020).
The thread 0x780 has exited with code -1073741792 (0xc0000020).
The thread 0x1930 has exited with code -1073741792 (0xc0000020).
The thread 0x1b24 has exited with code -1073741792 (0xc0000020).
The program '[13492] App1.exe' has exited with code -1073741792 (0xc0000020).
Activation of the Windows Store app '451e4789-01f8-4e4e-b28d-fbfa813a4513_v5p8rpnswjrxg!App' failed with error 'The app didn't start'.
```

Event Viewer #1

```
Activation via contract helper of the app 451e4789-01f8-4e4e-b28d-fbfa813a4513_v5p8rpnswjrxg!App for the Windows.Launch contract failed with Server execution failed.
```

Event Viewer #2

```
Activation of the app 451e4789-01f8-4e4e-b28d-fbfa813a4513_v5p8rpnswjrxg!App for the Windows.Launch contract failed with error: The app didn't start..
```

Event Viewer #3

```
ActivateApplicationForContractByAppIdAsUserWithHost of the app 451e4789-01f8-4e4e-b28d-fbfa813a4513_v5p8rpnswjrxg!App for the Windows.Launch contract failed with The app didn't start..
```

**TO REPRODUCE**

New Project -> Visual C# / Blank App (Universal Windows)

**ENVIRONMENT**

- Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition Update 1
- Windows 10 Pro 64bit Version 1511 10586.122

**TRIED**

- Repair Visual Studio
- Everything in [Unable to activate windows store app the app didn't start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19847563/unable-to-activate-windows-store-app-the-app-didnt-start)
- Rebuild, Clean, Manually delete bin, obj folders
- Uninstall app
- Checked permissions https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2798317
- Project is in C:\ [Unable to activate Windows Store app (Visual Studio 2015, Windows 10 Version 1511)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33704916/unable-to-activate-windows-store-app-visual-studio-2015-windows-10-version-151)
- There is no file 'app.config'
- sfc /scannow

I have wasted couple of days on this. Please help.

Messaging and Weather Apps also same error.

Comment: is the device unlocked as development PC (in settings app)?

Comment: Yes, it is in developer mode. I have been actively submitting to windows store.

Comment: If your code works fine in debug mode, but not in release mode, it is possible the problem with your code, [UWP apps use CoreCLR for Debug and .NET Native for Release](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2015/07/30/universal-windows-apps-in-net/).

Comment: As mentioned, release mode x64 is OK. Also its a blank app / uwp samples app

Comment: I have a similar issue - but for debug x86. The only solution is reboot.

Comment: Any chance you solved the problem?

Comment: Have you found a solution yet? :)

Comment: My developer workstation upgraded to Windows 10 Creator's Update.  Now -- every single x64 Debug app exhibits this same failure signature.  x64 Release is OK.  Happens with a vanilla blank UWP app.  MS #FAIL

Comment: Restarting visual studio solves the problem temporarily. After a while, it will have the same problem again.

Comment: I have the same problem, several months passed, no solution is found.

Answer (score -6, accepted):

Solution is the following...

1. Open Weather App
2. Error will popup, click Store link
3. Reinstall Weather app (ignore install error)

Answer (score 1):

To get the C# UWP to run in debug I went to Properties->Build and checked Compile with .NET Native tool chain.  This allowed me to debug.

Comment: That didn't solve the problem for me. Still can't debug, app launches but closes immediately.

Comment: I am facing the exact same problem, however it runs if I uncheck "Compile with .NET Native tool chain"