# Built-in Administrator account has no rights for some actions in Windows 10

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2015, win-universal-app, windows-10, access-rights

At some point I started getting following problems in Windows 10.

Microsoft Visual Studio 15 is showing the following error when I'm trying to run compiled Windows universal application:

> Unable to activate Windows Store app ... The activation request failed
>   with error 'This app can't be activated by the Built-in Administrator'

[image: Unable to activate Windows Store app ... The activation request failed with error 'This app can't be activated by the Built-in Administrator']

After trying to personalize Windows 10 desktop I'm getting the error message:

> This app can't be open Settings can't be opened using Built-in
>   Administrator account. Sign in with a different account and try again.

[image: This app can't be open Settings can't be opened using Built-in Administrator account. Sign in with a different account and try again.]

Few days ago everything was working fine with the same user account.
How can I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was related with User Account Control (UAC) settings. Some freshly installed software has disabled UAC.

Reverting UAC to default level and reboot helped me in both problems.

**How to set UAC Settings**

- Open User Account Control Settings by clicking the Start button, and
  then clicking Control Panel.
- In the search box, type uac, and then
  click Change User Account Control settings.