# How to run a Windows 10 IOT app locally?

Tags: c#, raspberry-pi, win-universal-app, iot, windows-10-iot-core

Is there a way to allow a normal Windows 10 installation to run Windows 10 IOT apps for debugging purposes?
Right now when I set the architecture from ARM (Raspberry Pi 3) to x64 (Local machine) I get the following error message when I start a debug session:

[image: Unable to activate Windows Store app. The activation request failed with error 'This program is blocked by group policy. For more information, contact your system administrator'.]

I've read [here](https://ms-iot.github.io/content/en-US/win10/EmbeddedMode.htm) that it's got something to do with 'embedded mode' but I can't find any information anywhere about it and the group policy does not appear to contain anything about enabling embedded mode...

Help is greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to run them on the device and do remote debugging. https://ms-iot.github.io/content/en-US/win10/AppDeployment.htm

Comment: @WiredPrairie that page also shows emulators

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - I'm not sure I understand your comment. The link I provided doesn't discuss (or even have the word) emulators

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It turns out that in addition to applying the policy, you also have to start the "Embedded Mode" windows service:

[image]

After that, everything works flawlessly. Just make sure to change ARM to x64 or x86.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to enabling the Embedded mode service, and you find the service cannot be started manually, one will need to run a provisioned package on the OS other than Win IOT Core that will set *AllowEmebeddedMode = 1*.

1. Download the Windows 10 ADK
2. Install it
3. Build a package
4. Run the package

The embeddedMode service should run automatically.

More info [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/docs/embeddedmode).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean with a Windows 10 IoT app if you don't mean an UWP app, and that [should be able to run on your PC](https://ms-iot.github.io/content/en-US/win10/samples/HelloWorld.htm#build-and-test-the-app-locally). Have you activated [*Developer Mode*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/get-started/enable-your-device-for-development) on your PC? If not, got to **System** → **Update & security** → **For developers** and choose **Developer Mode**. This will let you run all UWP apps, and not just those from the Windows Store.

Comment: A Windows 10 IoT app is a separate project type. It has nothing to do with Developer Mode. The CPU is different (ARM) so there is no way to run it locally outside an emulator

Comment: Ah, is it the Background Application we are talking about? I just created such a project and got a similar error. However mine was in Swedish (my language for Windows) and it makes absolutely no sence.

Comment: Unless the OP confused the terms . Other project types won't run on Windows 10 IoT on RaspberryPi though

Comment: Don't think so, I got a similar error now when testing.

Comment: UWP will definitely run on Windows 10 IoT core. In MS own Hello World-example for W10 IoT Core they are using a UWP-project: https://ms-iot.github.io/content/en-US/win10/samples/HelloWorld.htm

Comment: The application runs on Raspberry Pi 2s and 3s. However, in order to test a communication scenario, I need to bypass the SSL validation for a remote machine. Usually I accomplish this by running the server and the client on the same machine and use the IIS generated 'localhost' certificate.
I do need to run the IOT UWP Background app on a local machine.

Comment: The application should be possible to run locally. Have you tried this: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2750770 ? What version of Windows are you using?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavo Developer Mode is needed to sideload a UWP app locally. UWP-Apps (Headed apps) do run on Raspberrys! As the headless apps do as well. The only "special kind" for IoT is the headless template (background task), but its also a UWP App Template.