# Unable to activate windows app store - Install failed(VS 2015, UWP)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, uwp

I try to debug a UWP app that I developed, using UWP in VS 2015 Enterprise..
When I try to run it , I get the following message:
"Unable to activate windows store app (app name). The activation request failed with error 'Install failed'. Please contact your software vendor.

I know the question was asked before, I try the following:

- Uninstall the app
- Unistall VS
- PC restart
- Deleting all the build directories

Moreover, I checked and the app temporary file were created in
C:\Users(My User)\AppData\Local\Packages(App name)....

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Check this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/20270214/6249148
And this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13405577/6249148

And make sure you activated Developer Mode from settings.