# Hololens: no debug output in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, hololens, windows-mixed-reality

My task is very simple, I put in the `Main` method two lines:

```
Debug.Log("App START Debug.Log");
Debug.unityLogger.Log("App", "START Debug.unityLogger.Log");
```

and want to see these logs in the output if the app is running. If I set the run option as `Release`the app starts, but I don't see these logs. If I set the run option as `Debug` and try to start, I get an error popup:

> Unable to activate Windows Store app ´Template3D_pzq3xp76mxafg!App´

and the app doesn't start at all.

EDIT: according to comment of @Perazim, I have also tried:

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("App START Debug.Log");
```

No effect in `Release` and `Debug` mode.

EDIT 2:

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("App START Debug.Log");
```

works, if I put it in other methods, but doesn't work in the `Main()` method.

Comment: Have you tried [turning it off and on again](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13405577/1997232)?

Comment: tried, nothing changes

Answer (score 0):

[Debugger.Log](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.debugger.log?view=netframework-4.8) for the output to debugger. Debug.WriteLine prints to listeners. If there is no listeners, it will not work.

Answer (score 0):

My application stopped writing output to the output window with the System.Diagnostics.Debug.Writeline in debug mode. This all happened after the latest Microsoft Updates.

I created a new application just to see if it was my current application, and the new application would not write to the output window either.

Then I decided to right click on the Output Pane in Visual Studio and what do I see, Program Output unchecked.

[image: Program Output Unchecked]

I checked this and my Debug.Writeline works again.

Answer (score -1):

In unity you can use/see `debug.log();` in Visual Studio you need to use Console.WriteLine();

Comment: Then I get error: `The name 'Console' does not exist in the current context`

Comment: no effect with `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine()`