# Unable to activate Windows Store app on a Xamarin App that I am writing

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, windows-store

I am having big problems with my Xamarin App lately
For some reason my original app stopped compiling
So, i created a new Xamarin Mobile Application and copied the source code logic to the new app.
For now, I am trying to get the Windows app to work. It compiles and i can run it under Debug. But when i try to run the Release, I get this error:
Unable to activate Windows Store app XXXX!App. The activation request failed with error 'The app didn't start'

I looked in the System Event Viewer and I see this error:
The server XXXX!App did not register with DCOM within the required timeout.

I tried some of the suggestions in these sites, but they did not help:
https://appuals.com/fix-the-server-did-not-register-with-dcom-within-the-required-timeout/
https://www.partitionwizard.com/partitionmagic/the-server-did-not-register-with-dcom.html

What could be the cause of this error and how can i fix it?
thanks

Comment: Here are similar issues on SO : [Unable to activate windows store app the app didn't start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19847563/unable-to-activate-windows-store-app-the-app-didnt-start).,[Unable to Activate Windows Store App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13404315/unable-to-activate-windows-store-app).

Comment: none of the suggestions helped. some created different errors.